# How can i access my id from another xml file?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am making a bottom_bar with implementation `com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1` and I want to invoke `setOnTabSelectListener` on the bottombar items, but I can't find my bottombar items with R.id from xml file. What is my problem?

### My XML from res/layout/activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/tab"
    >
    </com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar>
</RelativeLayout>

    enter code here
```

### My XML from res/xml/tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab   
        id="@+id/home_tab"
        icon="@drawable/home_btn"
        />
    <tab
        id="@+id/search_tab"
        icon="@drawable/search_btn"
        />
    <tab
        id="@+id/new_post_tab"
        icon="@drawable/new_post_btn"
        />
    <tab
        id="@+id/profile_tab"
        icon="@drawable/profile_btn"
        />
</tabs>
```

### My class from java/com.ms.ma/MainActivity

```
 private void init_bottomBar(){

        bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {

                switch (tabId)
                {
                    case R.id.home_tab:      <--here i cant find home_tab-->

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue since updating to Android Studio 3.3

Comment: I see the same "cannot resolve symbol" error since updating Android Studio to version 3.3 but the project compiles and works. For some reason AS is not able to resolve the <tabs> tags in the xml file. None of the answers below did help.

Answer (score 2):

You can not find your id in your Activity if this id from another xml file

Try this method:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {

            switch (tabId)
            {
                case R.id.home_tab:      

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

**the mentioned library by you was depericated**

```
com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1
```

link: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

so that you cannot able to access.

Comment: in this link you can see xml file is in res/xml/bottombar_tabs.xml and used in layout/activity_main.xml and called in MainActivity.java , but i cant do this , Cannot resolve symbol 'home_tab'